# ScrollViewer Height changes when VerticalScrollBarVisibility is toggled between Hidden and Disabled

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have a `ScrollViewer` setup like this:

```
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller"
                          Focusable="False"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
```

When I change VerticalScrollBarVisibility from Hidden to Disabled, the height of the ScrollViewer goes from 115 to 107 (confirmed using Snoop).

I change nothing else.  I am stumpped.  I can't seem to figure out why this would happen.

I tried to reproduce it in Kaxaml, and it does not happen.

FYI: My specific example is a fairly complex prism app.

Any ideas why VerticalScrollBarVisibility would cause the Height of a ScrollViewer to shrink?  (And cut off the bottom of my controls.)

**Update:**

I did not think of it until Chris W. suggested it, but it is possible that this is related to my App Wide ScrollViewer style.  I am going to test and see if I can repro with that.  Here it is in case smarter minds than mine can find the issue quicker.  (It is quite long, but it is all needed to make the custom look:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
                    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Brush x:Key="ScrollBackground">#7F5F5F5F</Brush>
    <Brush x:Key="ScrollForeground">#DADADA</Brush>
    <Brush x:Key="ScrollDisabled">#E3E3E3</Brush>
    <Color x:Key="ScrollHashMarksDark">#656565</Color>
    <Color x:Key="ScrollHashMarksLight">#C2C2C2</Color>
    <System:Double x:Key="HashSize">1</System:Double>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Corner" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Width="8"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar" Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Height="8"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="HorizontalThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollForeground}" />
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollForeground}" />

                        <!--Add in the hash bars (in the middle of the scrollbar)-->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="3">
                            <Border Width="{StaticResource HashSize}" Margin="0,0,2,0" CornerRadius="30">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset=".75" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksLight}"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Width="{StaticResource HashSize}" Margin="0,0,2,0" CornerRadius="30">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset=".75" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksLight}"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Width="{StaticResource HashSize}" Margin="0" CornerRadius="30">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset=".75" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksLight}"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>



                        </StackPanel>
                        <Ellipse Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollForeground}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="VerticalThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollForeground}" />
                        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollForeground}" />
                        <!--Add in the hash bars (in the middle of the scrollbar)-->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="3">
                            <Border Height="{StaticResource HashSize}" Margin="0,0,0,2" CornerRadius="30">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset=".75" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksLight}"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Height="{StaticResource HashSize}" Margin="0,0,0,2" CornerRadius="30">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset=".75" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksLight}"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Height="{StaticResource HashSize}" Margin="0" CornerRadius="30">
                                <Border.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset=".75" Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksDark}"/>
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1"  Color="{StaticResource ScrollHashMarksLight}"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Ellipse Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="{StaticResource ScrollForeground}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>



    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ScrollBarGrid" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBackground}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollBar}}, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ScrollDisabled}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarGrid}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="true" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" Grid.Row="1">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb Style="{DynamicResource VerticalThumb}" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="VerticalGripper" Width="8"/>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="10"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                            <Grid x:Name="Bg" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarGrid}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageRightCommand}" Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="HorizontalGripper" Style="{DynamicResource HorizontalThumb}" Height="8"/>
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                </Track>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: You'll likely find your answer in the style template of either ScrollViewer or ScrollBar. Are you using the default templates or custom?

Comment: @ChrisW. - Ah, good suggestion.  I will post that too.

Comment: Could be that you have an item that wraps and when you give it more space it does not need to wrap.  Now if it is cutting off a control then that is a problem.

Comment: There's your answer dude, you showed a difference of 8px, and you have hard set height/width's on your ScrollBars of 8, so Disabled collapses their cells and the template abides by the difference..

Comment: @ChrisW. It is the vertical bar that I am disabling.  But the height is what is going shrinking....

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a closer look in a bit when I have a sec to try it out, but I'd be about certain it's just related to your templates but a quick adhoc review of them doesn't set off the immediate alarm bell of the exact culprit. Will re-visit later.

Comment: Oh wait....try rowspan=2 and columnspan=2 on both your bars  Edit: errr, I mean one or the other, sorry multi-tasking.

Comment: @ChrisW. - That makes it so that they overlap in the bottom right corner if I have both scrollbars visible.  (And the size still shrinks)

Comment: ya no worries, I'll get ya sorted in a minute when I have more than time to just write a sentence or two, trying to get crap deployed for the weekend first.

Comment: @ChrisW. - I changed the content of the scrollviewer from a dockpanel to a stackpanel and everything is working now.  (Not 100% sure why).  Either way, my app is working again. --  I am going to leave the question around in case someone finds an answer.

Comment: Hmm, well glad you got a remedy man but I finally got a minute to load this stuff up and take a look and I tried throwing a DockPanel in there and wasn't able to reproduce. Not sure where the culprit is now if just a change to a StackPanel is all it took to fix it, would guess somewhere in the children of the scrollviewer, the joys of troubleshooting ;)